# Query to remove the duplicates from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

I have on table called distance. It has 4 columns. **id, start_from, end_to** and **distance**.

I have some duplicate records. Duplicate records in the sense,

```
start_from   |   end_to    | distance
Chennai        Bangalore     350
Bangalore      Chennai       350
Chennai        Hyderabad     500
Hyderabad      Chennai       510
```

In above table, ***chennai to bangalore*** and ***bangalore to chennai*** both have **same distance**. So I need query to remove that record on **select**.

I want a out put like

```
start_from   |   end_to    | distance
Chennai        Bangalore     350
Chennai        Hyderabad     500
Hyderabad      Chennai       510
```

Comment: Please share the exact desired output. The field values might repeat but based on the requirement either we need to rewrite the query or redesign the table.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala Added desired output. I can't change the table.

Comment: Why do you want **Chennai** to **Bangalore**, not **Bangalore** to **Chennai**? And what if **Chennai** to **Hyderabad** is 350 as well, what would you want?

Comment: Chennai to Hyderabad is different start and end point. So I don't want to remove that one.

Comment: Then why do you choose to remain ***Chennai*** to ***Bangalore***, not ***Bangalore*** to ***Chennai***?

Comment: @Forward It can be ***Chennai to Bangalore**** or ***Bangalore to Chennai***

Comment: @shiva I think my answer is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no different between `Chennai to Bangalore` or `Bangalore to Chennai`, you can try this:

```
select
    max(`start_from`) as `start_from`,
    min(`end_to`) as `end_to`,
    `distance`
from yourtable
group by
    case when `start_from` > `end_to` then `end_to` else `start_from` end,
    case when `start_from` > `end_to` then `start_from` else `end_to` end,
    `distance`
```

Here is a [***demo***](http://rextester.com/PEYI86548) in rextester.

Even if `Chennai to Hyderabad` is 350 also works [***demo***](http://rextester.com/PWOFD26210).

And if you want `Bangalore to Chennai` to be remained, you can just change the place of `max` and `min`:

```
select
    min(`start_from`) as `start_from`,
    max(`end_to`) as `end_to`,
    `distance`
from yourtable
group by
    case when `start_from` > `end_to` then `end_to` else `start_from` end,
    case when `start_from` > `end_to` then `start_from` else `end_to` end,
    `distance`
```

also a [***demo***](http://rextester.com/WXZYD36793).

And `case when` will be compatible to most databases.

Comment: Yep, you are right. It looks better with case and when

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query to find the duplicates:

```
SELECT LEAST(start_from, end_to) AS start_from, 
       GREATEST(start_from, end_to) AS end_to, 
       distance
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY LEAST(start_from, end_to), GREATEST(start_from, end_to), distance
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**Output:**

```
start_from,   end_to,  distance
--------------------------------
Bangalore,    Chennai, 350
```

Now you can use the above query as a derived table to filter out the duplicates:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT LEAST(start_from, end_to) AS start_from, 
           GREATEST(start_from, end_to) AS end_to, 
           distance
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY LEAST(start_from, end_to), GREATEST(start_from, end_to), distance
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.start_from = t2.start_from AND 
           t1.end_to = t2.end_to AND 
           t1.distance = t2.distance    
WHERE t2.start_from IS NULL
```

The `WHERE` clause predicate, `t2.start_from IS NULL`, filters out duplicate records.

**Output:**

```
start_from  end_to     distance
--------------------------------
Chennai     Bangalore  350
Chennai     Hyderabad  500
Hyderabad   Chennai    510
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the field order (using values) in query helps to get an unique row:

```
select distinct
    case when start_from  > end_to then end_to     else  start_from end as _start,
    case when start_from  > end_to then start_from else  end_to     end as _end,
    distance
from distance;
```

After a test I get:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| _start    | _end      | distance |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Bangalore | Chennai   |      350 |
| Chennai   | Hyderabad |      500 |
| Chennai   | Hyderabad |      510 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: But last row should be `Hyderabad, Chennai, 510`

Comment: Yep, good one by using values order the fields and then filter the unique records. But as @Ullas mentioned ***start_from*** changed

Answer (score 0):

Assume your Table like

```
id  start_from              end_to                  distance
0   Chennai                 Bangalore               350
1   Bangalore               Chennai                 350
2   Chennai                 Hyderabad               500
3   Hyderabad               Chennai                 510
```

Then you can use the query compare with id.

```
Select 
    O.start_from,
    O.end_to,
    O.distance 
From 
    distance O
Left Join
    distance P
On 
    1 = 1
    and O.start_from = P.end_to 
    and O.end_to = P.start_from
Where 
    1 = 1
    and O.distance <> P.distance 
    or(O.distance = P.distance and O.id < P.id)
```

Comment: `CASE` vs `JOIN`. **CASE** is better. So it would better to use ***`CASE`***